# Cant extract Array of objects in firebase?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to send an array of objects from react js to firebase, I'm using a get method

```
const options = {
            method: "GET",
            headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" , "x-api-key": API_KEY_FIREBASE}      
          };

       await fetch(`${FIREBASE_URL}/update_users_profile?uid=`+uid+'&state='+status,options)
```

And the 'status' is my array of object which contain five elements.Its all working and passing to firebase, but  my firebase console is showing

```
[Object Object][Object Object][Object Object][Object Object][Object Object]
```

I have tried JSON.parse, but its not working,how can i extract my data in firebase

Comment: What API is this calling? `fetch(`${FIREBASE_URL}/update_users_profile?uid=`+uid+'&state='+status,options)`

Answer (score 0):

The console is showing that to keep the console log concise. To see the contents of the object file, you can choose array[0] or so and it should expand. This generally happens when the Objects have a lot of data in them and it's not practical to expand all of them and show.

Comment: no, i tried with one data still showing [Object Object]

Comment: Do you now what parameters the object has? Could you try array[0].parameter and see if something shows up